# Eclipse cross compiling in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

My end goal is to write a C based application to run on a 32-bit linux ARM board as an embedded system. I am running a virtual 64-bit Ubuntu OS with Eclipse Neon and I am struggling with getting a useable executable file.

I have setup the cross compiler and I have made sure to build in 32-bit.

To check the file type and get more information on it I have used the command

```
> file hello.elf
```

I got sample hello world executable that does work and the output of the file command is

> hello.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armf.so.3, for GNU/LINUX 2.6.32, BuildID

This program runs just fine, the output of the file command for my program (be-brave) is as follows, side note it's a simple hello world, I called it be-brave for motivation

> be-brave.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/LINUX 3.2.0, BuildID

My guess is that the issue is the GNU/LINUX differemce meaning my cross compiler is not set right but I don't know for sure and even if that is the case I don't know how to fix it.

Any and all pointers/suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround using the command line following this tutorial
[Installing ARM cross compiler](https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain)

I would still like to be able to use Eclipse so I will leave this question open in case anyone can help with that. I have a new issue, I am going to edit the original question to ask that